# More than one crop boxes on image using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am looking for out of box solution to have more than one crop boxes on the image. jcrop and imageareaselect pulgins dont seem to be supporting it.

any hack or other ideas i can support multiple image crop boxes on an image in browser.

Answer (score 2):

This will help you.

http://www.isdntek.com/tagbot/imap.htm

Comment: Really interesting finding. Code could be easily re-written to meet other similar requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fotonotes (www.fotonotes.net). I'm not sure if it's free, but go and take a look.